# Upgraded to GNOME 3 and no desktop icons showing

Tags: gnome, 17.04, desktop-icons

After switching to GNOME 3 I noticed my desktop icons, files etc.. are not showing although when I open the folder `/home/me/Desktop/` everything is there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the `gnome-tweak-tool` and navigate to the desktop tab as shown in the picture below and activate 'Show Icons'. If you don't have `gnome-tweak-tool` installed you can install it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Videonauth As I have two monitors is it possible to have the Primary monitor having the main icons and the rest gets extended to the second monitor? (main monitor on the left and extended on the right) or it must start from the monitors on the right first?

Comment: well your free to move the icons wherever you want on your screens :)

Comment: but they reset to the second monitor once I organize desktop by name or so :)

Comment: yes thats normal behavior and cant be changed, I for myself simply arranged them by hand and not changed them since.

Comment: There is no "Desktop" tab to go to, hence there are no "Show icons" to select/turn-on. Gnome tweaks version: 3.32.0-1, which is the latest as of now. @Videonauth

Answer (score 0):

If desktop section is not present in your Gnome Tweak Tools setting, Add desktop icon extensions from Gnome Extensions.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/

Comment: The desktop section is not present in my Tweak Tools. When I try to add desktop icon extensions following your link I get "This is an extension enabled by your current mode, you can't install manually any update in that session."